# Can a strong verb change to weak?

Tags: historical-linguistics, verbs, germanic-languages, proto-germanic

Can a strong verb in the course of time change to weak verb?

MoDu "scheiden" (to seperate) is weak: scheidde, gescheiden.

Its ancestor ODu *skeidan < PWGm *skaiþan < PGm *skaiþana is strong class 7a.

Declination in ODu class 7a would therefore be skied, geskeidan, but that doesn't feel right, since the examples of class 7a in grammars are all verbs ending in -on. What do I do wrong?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Many strong verbs transformed to weak verbs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_strong_verb#Gradual_disappearance

Comment: I don’t know much about Old Dutch, but the [Vroegmiddelnederlands Woordenboek entry](https://gtb.ivdnt.org/iWDB/search?wdb=VMNW&actie=article&id=ID24913) for this verb shows forms like _sciet_ and _geschieden_, which would seem to confirm that forms like _skied_, _geskiedan_ are reasonable enough. As for the question in the title, the answer is very clearly yes – strong verbs becoming weak has happened lots of times all over the Germanic languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A concrete example: [Old English *helpan*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/helpan#Old_English) was a strong verb, Modern English *help* is a completely regular weak verb.

Comment: "Completely"? I think the form "holp" did survive well into Modern English. Although, my spell checker doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: Oh, maybe you mean "modern English", with a lower-case m?

Comment: @Lorraine *holp*, *holpen* forms are still mentioned in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/help) and marked "(archaic)". Their usage was decreasing in last 3 centuries, but is not yet zero: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=holp%2Cholpst%2Cholpest%2Cholpen&year_start=1700&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @Arfrever add "helped" to that graph: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=holp%2Cholpst%2Cholpest%2Cholpen%2Chelped&year_start=1700&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 I don't think it makes sense to look at increasingly tiny numbers that were already tiny 3 centuries ago compared to the now-regular verb form.